# Node.js setup on Intellij Idea

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup node server on Intellij idea and all my startup code is present in package.json file but it asks for a js file. How do I fix it ?

Comment: Why would you put logic / startup code into a json file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the IntelliJ Node.js plugin uses the package.json file. You would need to run any npm commands manually, like `npm install`, and then point the IntelliJ plugin to the same JavaScript file that you have configured as the `"main"` script in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks for your input